# WPF: Trigger property from a nested child template

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, triggers, nested

I have a datagrid that has a nested datagrid in one of its columns. I need to trigger the main datagrid row background color from the count of rows in child datagid.

Here's a simplified example.

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding rigList}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=dataGridInner}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=dataGridInner}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item/Price" Width="220">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridInner" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" >
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="*"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
public class DataTable
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataTable> itemList { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        itemList = new ObservableCollection<DataTable>
        {
            new DataTable() {
                Items = new List<Item> {
                    new Item { Name = "Phone", Price = 220 },
                    new Item { Name = "Tablet", Price = 350 },
                },
                Description = "Electronic gadgets" },
            new DataTable() {
                Items = new List<Item> {
                    new Item { Name = "Teddy Bear", Price = 2200 },
                },
            Description = "Exclusive teddy bear" }
        };
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = itemList;
    }
}
```

[Here's the picture of the table this code yields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLpLQ.jpg)

So, by placing a trigger into datagrid's resources I can at least reach the child datagrid template using ElementName. But the setter apparently applies the Background property only within child's scope. What I need is that if child datagrid has two rows the entire parent row would be blue.

How it can be done?

Comment: I think you dont' need `, ElementName=dataGridInner` part of binding. `Items` is a property of row DataContext. And instead of putting style in `<DataGrid.Resources>` set `<DataGrid.RowStyle>` for dataGrid1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set the style as the RowStyle of the parent Grid. That's where you want to set background colors. You don't need to apply this style to the child, which is what you're doing by creating it in Resources as an implicit style for *all* instances of DataGrid row in that grid or any of its child controls (which is why it was working on the child grid).

Second, you're binding to a property of the parent grid row viewmodel, `Items.Count`. Therefore, there is no need to get the child grid control involved. Go straight to the collection that populates it.

Third, once you get the rows working, you'll notice that the child grid has a white background. In fact, the grid and the rows within it *both* have white backgrounds. I added a fix for that with a transparent background in the child grid's RowStyle property and on the child grid itself.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding rigList}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item/Price" Width="220">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid 
                        Background="Transparent"
                        x:Name="dataGridInner" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                        HeadersVisibility="None" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        CanUserAddRows="false" 
                        >
                        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="*"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```